# failed to change the color of the header and divider of the alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i don't understand why do i get a NPE...
this is my code :

```
    public void showSettingsAlert(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
    alertdialog.setTitle("Oups ! pas de données GPS");
    alertdialog.setMessage("GPS n'est pas activé sur votre appareil, voulez vous l'activer ?");

    /*
    handling the buttons :
     */
    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mcontext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    Dialog d = alertdialog.show();
    int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);

    // the next line is where i get the NPE :

divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green));
    TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green));

    alertdialog.show();

}
```

thanks for your help :)

PS : the color main_green does exist, i've used it somewhere else and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you should be using AlertDialog instead of Dialog here:

```
Dialog d = alertdialog.show(); //Use AlertDialog instead
```

Also you don't need to call `show();` again at the end of your method

**EDIT**

I just saw something I missed the first time I read your code. Please replace this:

```
AlertDialog d = alertdialog.show();
int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
```

with this:

```
AlertDialog d = alertdialog.show();
int dividerId = mcontext.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
int textViewId = mcontext.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
```

dividerId is null because you are giving the wrong `Context` to get the value. Or if your code is inside of an`Activity` you can just remove the mcontext part and do:

```
getResources().getIdentifier()... etc
```

Comment: Still not working :/ and for the second show(); I just forgot to delete it.

Comment: Is that method inside of an `Activity`?

Comment: I was missing the fact that i have a context on this class...I think this will work ! (will test it asap)